# Outlook 2007 open an email after sending

Tags: vba, outlook

I am looking for a way to have Outlook 2007 open an email after I send it (i.e. the actual sent email, not the draft).

I already have a macro setup to open the categories option after sending an email, but I need the actual email to open.

We use an add-in to upload our emails to a server, but it only works for sent email messages (i.e. emails not in the composition window).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Sent Items folder (retrieved using `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(ilFolderSentMail)`)